# Using read function of oData model in UI5

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5

I am coding an UI5 App which consumes a given OData Service. Now I want to get the name of an account with a given account number and Display it in a table. As I can only access the account Name via /AccountInfoSet()/ShortText I tried to use a formatter function to map the account number.

Binding in View:

Formatter function in Controller:

`numToNameFormatter : function(sNum){
        var text = this.getView().getModel().read("/AccountInfoSet('" + sNum + "')", null, null, true, 
        function(oData, oResponse){
            return JSON.stringify(oData);
        },
        function(){
            alert("Read failed");
        });
        return text;
    }`

This should return the requested object as a string. The data is requested successfully, as I verified via an alert. The problem is, that I can't get the data out of the call back, as it ist asynchronous. How do I get the data.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if your data model is set up like this, but would it be possible to **expand** your table set to also load the related `AccountInfoSet`'s?

I mean, if your table holds for instance an array of `Accounts`, and each `Account` entry has a related `AccountInfo`, you could just fill your table with the following:

`http://your.service/Accounts/?$expand=AccountInfo`

You then bind the field in your table directly, without a formatter:

`<TextField value="{AccountInfo/0/ShortText}">`